# PHPExcel: PHPToExcel not working correctly

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a date and time that is equal to `$date = '2014-10-28 13:00:00';`

When I get `$date = strtotime($date); // -> 1414526400`

Just to check if that converted correctly:

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $date); 

// Output: October 28, 2014, 1:00 pm
```

Then when I try to convert the PHP time to Excel time.

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($date);
```

I get `41940.83333` which in excel terms is `10/28/2014  8:00:00 PM`

I don't understand why the `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel()` static method isn't working... anyone know why `1PM` turns to `8PM`?

---

Edit:

When I change the start time to `1448744400` or `November 28, 2015, 1:00 pm` and run it in `PHPToExcel()`... it returns `42336.875` which in excel is `11/28/2015  9:00:00 PM`

Comment: Hmmm, possibly... How do I set the timezone in PHPExcel?

Comment: I'm not very familiar, you'll have to check the docs.

Comment: The Double data type expression used in Excel should work regardless of time zone as it's just `01/01/1900 00:00:00` plus whatever value is passed to it. At a guess it could be something to do with a conversion using floating point numbers and the known issues with trailing decimal places?

Comment: It's a timezone issue, as mentioned in the duplicate link i posted. Seems like it is expecting the time in UTC.

Comment: As @Arian says, PHPExcel assumes a UTC date/time. I'm actually in the process of assessing a PR to allow the method to accept a timezone adjustment: take a look at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/489

Comment: @MarkBaker Opps, I didn't see your reply until now.. I just submitted a pull request as well, my apologies. http://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/492